# SanDisk Ultra SD Card with Raspberry Pi 3+ Suddenly Stopped Working (and is Overheated!)

Tags: sd-card, boot-issues

It has been about a week since I booted into my Raspberry Pi.

This evening when I booted it, `raspberrypi.local` could not be detected on the network.

However the card was burning burning hot

I plugged SD card into different USB drives on both computers at home and it could not be detected.

I saw similar question on SE (cannot find link now) and the solution was to `replace the SD card` and `use SD card from reputable company`

My SanDisk Ultra SD Card was purchased from Amazon exactly a year ago.

Before I *purchase a pack* of SD Cards, **please recommend most reputed SD Card for Raspberry Pi**

Here is the one I purchased a year back

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> the SD card was burning burning hot

***Question***

Why my SD Card gets hot?

***Short Answer***

Because somewhere in the electronics circuit inside the card is shorted, causing a big current flowing, heating up things, therefore burning hot.

***Long Answer***

*Literature Search*

I googled forums for 5 minutes, but found wasting my time. :(

[Example forum discussion on burning hot SD Card problem](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49409/sd-card-overheats-pi3-model-b)

So I googled schematics, and found the following looking good. :)

[image: rpi model b sd card]

*SD Card Death Rate*

I counted the micro SD acrds I have been using for 4 years (Rpi 2/3 since 2015) , and found the following statistics:

Good = 21

Bad  = 4

In other words, the bad probability for a Rpi hobbyist is

(4 / (21 + 4)) = 16%

And bad cards per year is

4 / 5 = 0.8 ~= 1 bad card / yr.

[image: bad micro SD cards]

*Bad rate of SD card makers*

I counted the non SanDisk cards and found I used 3 Kingston cards, and 1 Toshiba.  So the ridiculously small sample size lying statistics is:

*Bad SD Card Maker Statistics*

Toshiba ~= 0%

SanDisk = (4 - 1）/ 24 ~= 13%

Kingston ~= 33%

*Postmortem*

Now I am going to use my cheap cheap multi-meter to do open/short resistance check to make a quick and dirty conclusion of why they were burnt to death.

Update 2019apr21hkt2219

I did not find any of the bad cards short circuited somewhere.  So I guess they are burning hot not because of short circuited current causing heating up.  To investigate further, I decided to buy a couple of new SD cards and see if copying Raspbian image also causes heating up.

[image: sd card pinout]

I copied the Raspbian 2019Apr image to four cards, as described by the picture below.

[image: copying image causing heating up]

[image: sd card adapter]

I also watched the following video to see what is inside the card.  I found it too complicated for me to dig deeper.  So I just make some conclusion and guideline for myself and other hobbyist programming newbies like me.

[Inside the SD Card - Data recovery of 'burnt' card - PITS  2018mar31](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkssPor7Gf0)

***Recommendations to newbies on buying, handling, and using micro SD card***

/ to continue, ...

Comment: How very interesting!